# Как вставить текст в поле ввода на сайте и нажать кнопку python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Есть один сайт, мне нужно с помощью Питона вставить в поле ввода на этом сайте ссылку и нажать на кнопку ввода этой ссылки. После должна открыться другая страница, где я должен получить другую ссылку и скопировать ее. Вроде как это можно через библиотеку Selenium, но не особо понял. Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Кажется, можно попробовать https://github.com/pyppeteer/pyppeteer

Comment: вполне, понять бы еще этот порт) с помощью seleniuma может можно?

Comment: Простите, не имел с selenium дело, имел дело только с JS версией https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer

Comment: В документации к порту пишут, что документация к оригиналу может быть полезна. В оригинале есть файлы с примерами обычных операций. Может, у вас получится переделать, вот пример на JS с вводом и нажатием на кнопку: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/examples/search.js

Comment: спасибо за помощь, попробую разобраться) но, конечно, хотелось бы с помощью селениума сделать, но если это поможет - почему нет)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pip install selenium`

Для использования `selenium` потребуется драйвер браузера - https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html#drivers
(расположить в той же папке что и скрипт)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep


# Открыть Chrome и перейти по указанному адресу:
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://m.vk.com/')

sleep(3)
# для поиска элемента в примере используется XPath (F12 в браузере, поиск нужного элемента, ПКМ - Copy - XPath)

# ввести в поле "Телефон и email" 123
eml = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mcont"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/form/dl[1]/dd/label/div/input').send_keys('123')

sleep(2)
# ввести в поле "Пароль" 456
phn = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mcont"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/form/dl[2]/dd/label/div/div[1]/input').send_keys('456')

sleep(2)
# нажать на кнопку "Войти"
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mcont"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/input').click()
```

`sleep` в примере указан для видимости действий.

Comment: большое спасибо, изучил уже библиотеку немного) только теперь не хочет находить кнопки по поиску с помощью названия класса. Вот пример: button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn btn-primary btn-lg button-full-download") Ошибка: Unable to locate element: .btn btn-primary btn-lg button-full-download Получается не может найти эту кнопку, хотя она полюбому есть. В чем может быть проблема? Явные ожидания пробовал, не помогло

Comment: Используйте XPath, как в примере. Так же, если ответ полезе, вы можете отметить его как решение, это поможет другим участникам

Comment: отметил) да, думаю xpath поможет, попробую. Читал, что у некоторых по одному типу находит, а по другому нет